# Datatables: Can't interact with a row after searching

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I've initiated a datatable plugin as following:

```
var table= $("#mytable").DataTable({

    ajax: "list.json",
    columns: [
        {"data": "name"},
        {"data": "location"},
        {"data": "date"}
    ],
    searchCols: [
        {"search": "John"},
        null,
        null
    ]
});
```

The example above also does a pre search on the first column. Now, when the plugin is initiated I want to interact with some of its rows:

```
fnInitComplete: function() {
   $(this).find("tr").click( ... );
}
```

Everything works good, UNTIL I try to interact with a row that's been searched on the table render `{"search": "John"}` and that was searched again after (e.g. I changed the search query to "Richard" and tried to click on one of that rows). Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use delegated event handlers because jQuery DataTables manipulates DOM on each table draw.

For example:

```
var table= $("#mytable").DataTable({   
    ajax: "list.json",
    columns: [
        {"data": "name"},
        {"data": "location"},
        {"data": "date"}
    ],
    searchCols: [
        {"search": "John"},
        null,
        null
    ]
});

$("#mytable").on("click", "tr", function(){
   // Handle click event
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I came to this too.